# My form opens then closes when i launch it

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to start my form, it flashes like it never opened.

I have already looked into my code and there is nothing wrong

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Initialization : Form
{
    public Initialization()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task Wait1(int Milliseconds)
    {
        await Task.Delay(Milliseconds);
    }

    private async void Wait(int Millisecondsdew)
    {
        Wait1(Millisecondsdew);
    }
    private void Initialization_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Initialization");
        ///Setup Stuff///
        ShowIcon = false;
        ControlBox = false;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        Text = "";
        /// Start Initializing///
        richTextBox1.Text = "Initializing....";
        Wait(1000);
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Lazy Tools\AdditionalFiles.exe"))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "Initializing.... \n Software Installers 1 Exists";
            Wait(1000);
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Lazy Tools\SoftwareInstallers2.exe"))
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n Software Installers 2 Exists";
                Wait(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please reinstall software store, \n Software Installers 2 is missing");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please reinstall software store, \n Software Installers 1 is missing");
        }
    }
}
```

The async works fine on my first form, but this is the second form. When I call up the second form, it flashes and it like never opened.

Comment: *I have already looked into my code and there is nothing wrong.* Clearly there is something wrong, or you wouldn't be having this issue. Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger to see what's happening? How do we reproduce the issue based on the code you've posted here?

Comment: How exactly do you open the form?

Comment: What second form? you havent shown where you are calling this, how are you proving you are actually calling the form show twice?

Comment: @Ahmed Form2 ss = new Form2();
ss.ShowDialog();

Comment: The problem is indeed reproducible. See my answer below.

Comment: All three properties you set (ShowIcon, ControlBox, FormBorderStyle) are "difficult" properties.  They affect the underlying CreateWindowEx() call.  When you change them after that call is already made, such as in the Load event handler, then Winforms has to do something nasty, it has to call CreateWindowEx() again.  This has side-effects, for one it causes ShowDialog() to complete because the original window got destroyed.  That's a bug, but won't get fixed.  The proper place to set these properties is in the constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for sharing your valuable insights! I always appreciate your input and explanation of such behaviors. That being said, as per my tests (see my answer below), this only happens when setting the `Text` property to an empty string (after setting `ControlBox` to false). The other two properties `ShowIcon` and `FormBorderStyle` don't seem to produce the bug. Is that something that might not happen all the time or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting the `ControlBox` property to false *and then* setting the `Text` property to an empty string *after the form has loaded* causes the form to close (which seems like a bug).

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
// Using other events like `Form_Shown` or even a `Button_Click` still has the same behavior
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.Text = "";
}
```

As a workaround, you may, instead, set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `FormBorderStyle.None`:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

..which will have a similar effect to what you're trying to achieve. This is actually the standard way to hide the title bar.

If you don't want to hide the border or you actually want to use the `ControlBox` and the `Text` properties, you can do any of the following:

- Set those two properties at design-time. Or...
- Move those two lines to the constructor of the form:

  ```
  public Initialization()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.ControlBox = false;
      this.Text = "";
  }
  ```
- Or make sure to set the `Text` property *before* the `ControlBox` property:

  ```
  private void Initialization_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      this.Text = "";
      this.ControlBox = false;
  }
  ```